# Common MUI theme for multiple Project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, themes

using createTheme I have created a theme for my project, it works fine.
My question is how can I use that particular theme for my other projects without copying it again n again.

I asked this Ques. with Mui team they replied " Concerning your question, you can store your theme in a "shared" repository and use this repo as a dependency on all your projects. Once the theme is changed in the shared repo, all other projects would get the changes."

please let me know an efficient way of using it.How to create shared Repository.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement some solutions from the blog post [Extending the theme in Material UI with TypeScript](https://www.bergqvist.it/blog/2020/6/26/extending-theme-material-ui-with-typescript):

In the shared project/components lib I created a ThemeInterface.ts file. This file has the extra properties that I want in my projects.

```
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';
export type Modify<T, R> = Omit<T, keyof R> & R;

export type CustomTheme = Modify<
  Theme,
  {
    space: {
      small: number,
      general: number,
    },
    borderRadius: {
      general: number
    },
    layout: {
      sidebar: {
        citizenBackGroundColor: React.CSSProperties['color'];
      };
    };
  }
>;
```

Then I use it where I create the theme (this is still in the shared project)

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';
import { CustomTheme } from './ThemeInterface';
export function createCustomTheme(): CustomTheme {
    const baseTheme = createTheme({
    //Here you can set your palettes etc.. 

    });

    return {
        ...baseTheme,
     //Here comes the properties that we added before 
        space: {
            small: 2,
            general: 4,
        },
        borderRadius: {
            general: 2,
        },
        layout: {
            sidebar: {
                //themeColors.secondary is just a const 
                citizenBackGroundColor: themeColors.secondary
            }
        },
    }
}
```

I have setup my components lib with rollup an story book.

In the project that is consuming the shared theme you can now do this:

```
// App.tsx
const theme = createCustomTheme();

 <ThemeProvider<CustomTheme> theme={theme}>
```

As a side note. When using storybook in your components you might need to useTheme this way otherwise it wont recognize your typings..  But this should not be needed in the consuming projects.

```
const theme = useTheme<CustomTheme>();
```